# How to change multiple jLabel's text Dynamically in a single for loop?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Is it possible ?

I have 5 Labels on jFrame as jLabel1, jLabel2, jLabel3, jLabel4 and jLabel5. I want to set text as null other than a single one which is input given by user. For experiment, I am using 5 labels but there are more than 150 labels in my project.

Ex : suppose user given the input in the jTextField1 as 2 then I want to set all jLabels text as null except jLabel2 in a single for loop.

```
String count = jTextField1.getText();
 int cnt = Integer.parseInt(count);
for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
  {
    String lbl = "jLabel"+i;
    if(i!=cnt)
      {
        lbl.setText(null);
      }
  }
```

Please Help!

Comment: yes or it may be static as 'Label' to all other than the user defined.

Comment: "I have 5 Labels on jFrame as jLabel1, jLabel2, jLabel3, jLabel4 and jLabel5." - That's the first problem. Why do you have those all as separate variables rather than a collection or array? You're mimicking a collection by using separate variables - instead of that, just use a *real* collection.

Comment: What you trying to do is widely considered as bad design. But if you want it you can iterate thou all fields and filter thous who is JLabel and match your pattern. See reflection API

Comment: It's better for the Swing layout manager to set a JLabel as blank (" "), rather than null.

Comment: I'm a bit concerned when you state that you're using 150 JLabels, and I wonder if you'd be better off using a JList or JTable.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels      yes I just realised. Removing my earlier comment.

Comment: Actually I am using it for pattern matching!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Name the JLabels ascending, something like:

```
JLabel[] jLabel = new JLabel[1500];
    for (int i = 0; i < jLabels.length; i++) {
        jLabel[i].setName(String.valueOf(i));
        //You can also setText at the labels
    }
```

And then:

```
    String count = jTextField1.getText();
    for(int i = 0; i<=jLabels.length; i++) {
             if (!jLabel[i].getName.equals(count) {
                  //DO WHATEVER YOU WANT
                  jLabel[i].setText(" ");
              }
     }
```

Comment: It is not affecting on the real taken at design time jLabel's property.

Comment: Yes, all listeners are set up correctly but not working......But I think your code is right.